# Browser doesn't set cookie, despite of response header

Tags: php, angularjs, cookies

I have a AngularJS web application with a REST-API (written in PHP). My JS App has a 'POST' method for the login.

1. I 'post' my username and login to an API
2. The post is successful, and the response header has 'set-cookie'

[image]

I can also see the cookie via Chrome Dev Tools in the response:
[image]

But the Browser doesn't set it. Does anybody have a suggestions or a solution for this?

EDIT: My POST-method is a Ajax call via jQuery.

Comment: So... your AJAX call sets the session?

Comment: Can you post your actual code ?

Comment: Ok, sorry, i found the error. I am developing on my localhost (via IP 127.0.0.1 so cookies are getting set), but the cookie I get is just valid for a specific domain name.

Answer (score -1):

You can't set cookie on localhost in Chrome.

1) Try to use other domain mapped to localhost like example.com
You can edit your hosts file and add "127.0.0.1 example.com" there

2) set cookie domain = "";

3) set cookie max age.

4) check your browser cookies settings, might be you added any custom cookie rules as well

After that if chrome will be in a good mood it will set that cookie.